# objective-c properties - no attribute

Tags: objective-c, properties

I've just started reading through the Object-c developer handbook from apple.  I'm playing with properties.  I declared a class interface which has two properties:

```
@interface SocialEnglish : NSObject <IsSociable>
@property int numberOfPeopleMet;
@property (readonly) int readOnlyProperty;
@end
```

without declaring the instance variable associated to the properties.  To my surprise, the compiler didn't complain.  Then I wrote a bunch of code to access the instance object and sure enough the setters and getters worked as if I had implemented them and associated them to instance variables!

In the declaring class I can do something like this:

```
...
_readOnlyProperty = 3;
...
```

hmmm...I gota say as helpful as this maybe...I don't like it.  Why doesn't the compiler complain and instead generates code.  Is there a setting I need to set.

Also please note that I don't have a  `@synthesize`  directive in my implementation class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest versions of Xcode automatically "`synthesize`" declared properties for you now.  [This came in with Xcode 4.0](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/developertools/rn-xcode/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW105) (see the linked release notes under "Compiling: LLVM2.0").

If you want to call "`@synthesize`", or declare an "`_readOnlyProperty`" ivar or static and "`@synthesize`" to that, or write your own setters & getters, you can continue to do this.